# How can I ensure that a Rust executable is run with root permissions on Linux?

Tags: rust, permissions, root, user-permissions

I would like to ensure my executable is run with `root` permissions under Linux. i came up with this:

```
use std::env;
use std::process::exit;

fn main() {
    match env::var("USER") {
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Something went wrong: {:?}", e);
            exit(2);
        }
        Ok(name) => {
            if name != "root" {
                println!("Must be root...");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    println!("ok!");
}
```

Is there a more concise / idiomatic way to do this? How could I have access to the effective user id (EUID)?

Comment: https://docs.rs/nix/0.17.0/nix/unistd/fn.geteuid.html

Comment: @Shepmaster how could i miss this?! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Shepmaster would you like to post an answer for future reference? (if not: would you allow me to use your input to post a full answer?).

Comment: I don't know how to answer your actual question ("ensure that a Rust executable is run with root permissions on Linux"). For example, I don't know that using the EUID is the right thing. Any information in comments is encouraged to be placed into an answer — comments are ephemeral.

Comment: Generally, you don't, you try to do the work and look what is the error. If it's a permission problem, the user will know. If you already know you expect to be root, a more helpful message would be to say "Are you sure you are running it as root ?"

Comment: I strongly support @Stargateur advice. What if the user needs to run your app in some ~/myapp folder, where every file belongs to him? Or what if the user already is in some privileged group which allows him to access some device?

Being root does not necessarily increase security. Forcing being root probably decrease security.

Comment: @AndreaRossini my use-case is an edge case: i am rewriting a small utility (that i use myself) that verifies that dm-crypt/cryptsetup uses the masterkey i provided. this will need to have root permissions (i have no reason to give permissions for cryptsetup in sodoers). this is not meant to increase security; i just know my program will be calling things that need root access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've found (and what is used in [`libcryptsetup-rs`](https://github.com/stratis-storage/libcryptsetup-rs)) is this:

```
use nix::unistd::Uid;

fn main() {
    if !Uid::effective().is_root() {
        panic!("You must run this executable with root permissions");
    }
}
```

Whether to `panic!`, `println!`, or `exit` is up to the programmer to decide.